# Save the information in a RealmList locally

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, realm

I'm trying to create a list of objects using Realm.io. I've managed to create a RealmList of objects that extend Realm objects and convert it to a recycler view that displays all of the objects in the RealmList. I've also added the ability to add objects to the list.

However, whenever I close and re-open the app, all of the items that I added to the RealmList previously are gone and the list is started from scratch. How can I save a RealmList locally so that all of the items added to the list will remain when the app is closed and opened again?

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your Realm objects definition and you have `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()` in you Realm initialization all realm data is cleared.

If you don't have that option or you don't modify definitions data has to be the same between application restarts.

Answer (score 0):

You should save the entities you put in the `RealmList<T>` into the Realm in a transaction, like so:

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(realmList);
});
```

If you're not doing that, then you're just tinkering with your objects in memory in a fancy list, but you're never actually writing them to the Realm.